# scrolling bug in Chrome and Opera: related to Ajax?

Tags: google-chrome, opera, vertical-scrolling

We have just encountered a Chrome (65.0.3325.181) and Opera (52.0.2871.37) scrolling bug.  This is on an intranet page so I can't give you a URL. But if the following *symptoms* are familiar to you, and you know the specific cause and a fix, please advise.

The scrollbar appears, and about 9 of 50 items can be scrolled vertically into view, at which point scrolling stops. **It's as if the page believes there are no more items to be displayed.**

However, if a new tab is opened and the URL from the broken page is pasted into its address bar, so that the page is retrieved from cache, *scrolling works perfectly in the new tab.*